# Spring Security redirects to forbidden page(403)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring-security on top of spring-mvc application. Few points about the application I am working on.

1. Home page is login page i.e /users(). Login menu served as HTML dropdown menu.
2. Implementing `userDetailsService()` and `UserDetails()` instead of `AuthenticationManager`/provider
3. Required is person to view the home page without any roles.

Current situation :

1. Redirects it to 403 page mentioned in the entrypoint-ref.
2. No idea how to redirect it to user.jsp or /users
3. All examples I can find on net somehow show same stuff which is implementing `AuthenticationManager. Some code :

security-context.xml

```
<import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <!-- Global Security settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />


    <!-- Spring Security framework settings -->
    <security:http pattern="/users" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="formAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="5" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" requires-channel="any" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" access="permitAll" />
    </security:http>
    <!-- queries to be run on data -->
    <beans:bean id="formAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="LoginServiceImplementation" class="com.WirTauschen.service.LoginServiceImpl"></bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

LoginServiceImpl :

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            User user = userDao.findByName(username);
            if(user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(user);
    }
}
```

Login-form(part of hompage HTML code enveloped in user.jsp)

```
<nav class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li class="purple"><a href="#"><i class="icons icon-user-3"></i> Login</a>
                    <ul id="login-dropdown" class="box-dropdown">
                        <li>
                         <form id="form" action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method="POST">
                            <div class="box-wrapper">
                                <h4>LOGIN</h4>

                                <div class="iconic-input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" value="">
                                    <i class="icons icon-user-3"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="iconic-input">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="">
                                    <i class="icons icon-lock"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="loginremember"> <label for="loginremember">Remember me</label>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="orange" value="Login">
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#">Forgot your username?</a>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                <br class="clearfix">
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <h4 class="pull-left">NEW CUSTOMER?</h4>
                                <a class="button pull-right" href="create_an_account.html">Create an account</a>
                            </div>
                             </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icons icon-lock"></i> Create an Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Form-login from security-applicationContext.xml

```
 <security:form-login login-page="/users" default-target-url="/users"/>
```

Any help would be nice. Never knew spring-security will be nothing but torture.

Comment: Your user gets never authenticated, how should it? There is no `login-form` configured and as such nothing that reads the username/password and nothing will ever authenticate your user. The main problem is you are doing too much yourself, you don't need the custom entry point, just use the default `form-login` for that.

Comment: Do you mean Login-Form as the HTML code, it is there. I have not posted it. I am editing post to paste it.

Comment: No the `login-form` as in the xml configuration. That is the configuration part that registers a filter that listens to a url and processes login attempts. If you don't add that there will be nothing that authenticates your user...

Comment: Thank you. I have added form-login from another example, but as I have stated, my login part is part of the Homepage i.e the user.jsp, there is no HTML file. I can initiate the homepage by calling localhost:8080/users. If this is not what you meant, can you post some sample code for form-login. THank you.

Comment: I added form login in my code with login page as /login and default-target-url as /users.

Comment: That doesn't matter where your login-form is. That form has to post to the url that the filter (configured by `form-login`) is listening to. It doesn't matter what triggers that URL.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said above. Can you please paste some pseudocode, I am no spring-security expert. I am adding a line, where login page is also users, and redirection by default-target-url is also users. Please check.

Comment: Yes. Its inside a form " <form id="form" action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method="POST">". The homepage and loginpage are same as user.jsp. Right now, my form-login reads as <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/users"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/users" access="permitAll"/>. But I am redirected to /login again and again.

Comment: I suggest a read of [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login) as that explains quite a lot instead of trial-and-error. The default url the filter listens to is `/j_spring_security_check` and not `/login` if you want to change that modify the `login-process-url` of the `form-login` element.

Comment: @M.Deinum he says he uses Spring Security 3.2.5, so you can use /login...

Comment: No that only is for java based configuration not for xml configuration.

Comment: Ok. I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You have to understand how Spring works: the client tries to get to a protected resource (users page, for example); if he did not login yet, he is being redirected (Spring redirects him) to the login page.

In your Spring beans.xml you declare what is your login page. If you put there "/login.html", you have to make sure that you have this kind of page, with the login form. After the user logs in, Spring will redirect him back to the /users.

Makes sense?

**UPDATE II**

You can make (like Amazon...) a landing page (e.g. index.html) which is public, meaning users can see it without logging in. Then, there are links there to 'protected resources', and if a user try to click on it and get the protected resource, Spring will redirect him to the login page. If you wanna do that, you put you 'protected resources' under a specific directory (e.g. /secured) and you place there all prote**c**ted resources HTML/JSP/etc. You configure this in the beans.xml: (note here that 'welcome' page is non-secured, everybody will be able to see it without login)

```
<sec:http pattern="/welcome" security="none" />

 <sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

Comment: No, it is 3.2.5, that is why I am just using username,password and submit..Instead of anything else. Did you checked out the form-login I had posted above? Right now I just redirected to login page even when I have used permitALL for /users.

Comment: I am unable to get inside the homepage itself to login. As soon as I click on applicationname/users, immediately it goes to /login. And there is nothing named /login. So I get a 404.

Comment: Yes. Makes sense. I know. But for example, go on amazon.com. It doesnt tell you immediately to login. I want that behavior. I dont know why it is taking me straight to login.

Comment: Thanks for helping, ok, now you told me how to make access secure, but I want to land on /users which is my Homepage without any login.So i added <security:intercept-url pattern="/users" access="permitALL"/>, and it doesnt work, it still takes me directly to login.

Comment: i've update my answer... (added example sec:http pattern="/welcome" security="none"

Comment: I had found that before, but I dont know if Spring Security has made some changes in their code, wherever I add that line with /users, I get an error. Do you know the location to add where security="none" wouldnt result in an error.

Comment: you can see in my answer where to add the line with the security="none" - it is a different http block. when you try it you get an error ? this is an example: https://github.com/OhadR/Authentication-Flows/blob/master/client/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml